# Convert result_array() to JSON object

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

What i am trying to do is convert `result_array()` given by my query and directly convert it into JSON object , which can further be set in controller like this:

```
$this->response($jsonobject, REST_Controller:: HTTP_OK);
```

my attempt by studying several SO questions :

```
$this->response(json_encode($result_array), REST_Controller:: HTTP_OK);
```

but my attempt is wrong i think because it return json itself in form of `string` , how to achieve this then?

**Example:**

```
$pakistan = array('status' => 'OK','message' => 'yes i am ok');
// convert pakistan to something like
$pakistan = [ 'status' => 'OK','message' => 'yes i am ok' ];
```

Comment: post an example

Comment: just posted example @PathikVejani

Comment: What framework are you using, json encode gives a string representation of an object/array. Have you tried just passing result_array to response?

Comment: nop , didn't tried it yet , but i think that's bad idea , it is expecting object as response not array

Comment: @BenCummins just tried your theory , and got `500: Internal Server Error
`

Comment: Ok try json_decode(json_encode($result_array))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to return the query `result` not `result_array`

model function

```
function getRecords(){
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);
   return $query->result();
}
```

Convert to json

```
$object = getRecords();
$json_obj = json_encode($object);
```

Comment: should i pass `$object` or `$json_obj` to response ?

Comment: Pass the $json_obj to response

Comment: I don't know why some one voted my answer down, did I some thing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for hint , solution was using result() instead of result_array() ,